# How do i configure "ws" websocket on nginx nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

I am currently trying to deploy my NODEJS application on a nginx debian remote server .
It works very well in localhost.
But I have some difficulties to make websocket work in remote nginx server.
I use "ws" nodejs module.

This is how i declared my websocket server side :

```
var WebSocket_ = require('ws');
var wss = new WebSocket_.Server({port: 40510});
```

And this is how i opened my websocket client side :

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:40510');
```

I know i have to configure /etc/nginx/sites-available/default on my Nginx VPS :

Do i need to add a websocket block location and define a specific proxipass ?
If yes how ?

Do I have to replace var "ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:40510');" by another instruction in my client side code ?

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 7):

If you already have a server block, put this inside (usually inside sites-available or nginx.conf):

```
location /ws {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:40510;
}
```

Now, depending on your Nginx listening ports you will configure your client IP/Port (By default Nginx listens on port 80)

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:80/ws');
```

Full configuration file (example):

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    server {
        listen       localhost:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;

        # Logs
        access_log /var/log/nginx/main.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/main.error.log;

        # Websocket
        location /ws {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:40510;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And you confirm, i don't have to change anything in the instruction "var wss = new WebSocket_.Server({port: 40510});" ?

Comment: If it is working by now without Nginx, it should be fine as it is.

Comment: My server listen config :
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

Comment: in fact, apparently client-side, the websocket address must start with ws: //

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL's scheme must be either 'ws' or 'wss'. 'http' is not allowed.

Comment: Since the library you are using does not validate http://, starting with ws:// will do. If you want to use wss:// you have to configure a new Nginx Server Block listening on port 443 using ssl.

Comment: ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:40510');

Comment: i have this console message :

Comment: admin_playlist.js:106 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:40510/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: My question is:
Should I create a new server block (server {}), specific for the "location / ws" or do I have to put it in the same server block?
Putting it in the same block, I got an error 502: I presume that this is caused by the "location /" which has priority over "location / ws". thus the route "/ ws" is never treated

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much

I already use a block location, with a redirection proxi reverse :

```
    location / {


           proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

should not I use my domain name instead?
Something like:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('http://vincentfritz-dev.fr/ws');
```

?