# Can't access Node.js websocket service from Angular in production

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, amazon-ec2, websocket

I'm facing a trouble while deploying a fullstack app into AWS EC2 instance.

I have my backend node.js app running on port 5000
I have my frontend Angular app handled by nginx on port 80
Both on the same instance.

I have managed to allow basics http calls but I didn't find the way to allow ws connection between my front and my backend.

Following code is the part I added in my nginx.conf file, in a server block, to allow communication between the 2 apps :

```
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;

    #FRONTEND angular files
    location / {
        root /my_frontend_folder_path;
    }

    #BACKEND node/express proxy redirects
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

Angular side, here is how I connect to my websocket :

```
    this.socket = new WebSocket(ws://localhost:5000/ws);
    this.socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection established.');
    };
```

It works perfectly in my local machine but I got a "Connection refused" when I try to access it in my deployed app.

Apparently, [the closest question I found here wasn't answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477693/how-do-i-configure-ws-websocket-on-nginx-nodejs-server)

I've tried different nginx conf that I found on web but none allows me to have a working service.

My expectation is to be able to connect to my websocket from my frontend hosted in the same instance.

EDIT : Finally I'm able to connect to my WS by changing his url client-side. I use the public IP address of my instance, I don't like this way but for now I just want to progress. But just after the connection is established successfully, it immediately closes with following error :

```
CloseEvent
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
code: 1005
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
reason: ""
returnValue: true
srcElement: WebSocket {}
target: WebSocket {}
timeStamp: 482
type: "close"
wasClean: true
```

Any help would be very appreciated <3

Comment: Hello there, 
I've managed to have access to my websocket by changing, client-side, the url of the websocket by the public IP address of my EC2 instance. So, the connection is well established but it closes immediately after sending his first response... 

If someone has an idea of why it happens and how to solve it, it would be very helpful for me <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found where was MY mistake...

nginx was "eating" a part of my url, so I've just added a '/ws' in my url...

```
this.socket = new WebSocket(ws://<INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP>/ws/<NORMAL_WS_SERVER_ENDPOINT>);
```

Hope my brainless issue will help someone in the future xD